# Purchase order invoice status Unpaid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, invoice, purchase-order

Does anyone know how to set purchase order invoices automatically to "Unpaid" in Magento 2? 
Right now they are automatically marked as paid, but they should really be marked to Unpaid, and then set to Paid by the the administrator when the money is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out that to change this I would need to change this to true:

vendor/magento/module-payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php

```
protected $_canCapture = true;
```

Then to make it the default value:

vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/invoice/create/

```
<option selected value="not_capture"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Not Capture')) ?></option>
```

Obviously I should put these changes in a new module.